# Easy CSS edit to center the entire page

Tags: html, css

you can see my jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fcZQV/ where I posted the HTML and CSS of my page. You can see the result also in http://fiddle.jshell.net/fcZQV/show/ for better viewing example.

The `#sidebar` and `#feed` must come close and all of the page in the center of screen.

How can I do this? I tried `margin:0 auto;` but nothing...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also set the width of the page.  Then it will center inside that width.

```
margin: 0 auto; width: 980px;
```